# Changing the default page in BlazorWebAssembly not working

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

using Visual Studio 2019, I created a Blazor Web Assembly project.

I want to use the index.html page for something else, so I removed the `<app></app>` tag from it.

Then created another page named `dashboard.html` and added a `dashboard.razor` page. In this page added `@page "/dashboard"` and the `<app></app>` tag.

Now when I navigate to `dashboard.html` from index.html, am getting message "`there is nothing at this address"`

How could I make the dashboard.html page as my main app page?

Any ideas most appreciated.

This is how the project properties look:

[image]

Comment: It's a while since I saw an `<app></app>`. What version are you on?

Comment: And: where is @page "/", how do you navigate etc. See [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I am using .NET Framework Standard 2.1. Its the one generated by Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: At the moment I do not have @page "/". Is that a must to have?

Comment: .net standard doers not do Blazor at all. Start by updating VS to the latest version and create a new project, make sure to select .net5 in that wizard.

Comment: I have the latest version. I just added the property page.

Comment: That's not the latest version, should be .net 5.x something.

Comment: OK. Cos .NET does not even appear in the list. I think VS is messed up then?

Comment: .net5 is the latest release, usually comes with a VS update. So what is your VS version?  Help|About shows me 16.10.3

Comment: And that properties page can't be a Blazor project...  You should see at least .net core 3.x

Comment: OK, so I am running Visual Studio Professional v16.10.4, and yet I am on an old Blazor project template?

Comment: I think i got, i had to change the framework to 5, but this leaves my original question unsolved.

Comment: Please show us your startup.cs (for the server project), dashboard.html, index.razor and dashboard.razor files.  This takes a little more wiring up than most believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this running I suggest you set up a blank WASM project from the Blazor template.  Once you have it running you can make the necessary changes to your project.  (My project is called *Blazor.Starter.WASM*.)

Move the *Client* project *wwwroot* to the *Server* project.

Copy *index.html* to *dashboard.html* - here's
*serverproject/wwwroot/dashboard.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Blazor.Starter.WASM</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Blazor.Starter.WASM.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="/site.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My simple *index.html* looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Blazor.Starter.WASM</title>
    <base href="/"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="m-4 p-4">
        <a href="/dashboard">Go to Dashboard</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Index.razor* looks like this.  Note the two page references

```
@page "/"
@page "/dashboard/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    Welcome to your new app.
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
}
```

*Counter.razor* and all other *pages* in the SPA - add `@page "/dashboard/nnnnn"`

```
@page "/counter"
@page "/dashboard/counter"
.....
```

*NavMenu.razor* looks like this (changes to the hrefs):

```
.....
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="dashboard" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="dashboard/counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="dashboard/fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
            </NavLink>
        </li>
......
```

Finally update *Startup.cs* on the Server project.

```
....
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

           // New section to map all requests starting with /dashboard to the Blazor Wasm project
            app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/dashboard"), app1 =>
            {
                app1.UseRouting();
                app1.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("dashboard.html");
                });

            });

            // default endpoint
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If I have these instructions correct the application should start on the simple index page.  Once in the WASM try an F5 to check the Endpoint mapping works correctly - note all `@page` references within the SPA must be prefixed with `/dashboard` to ensure the F5 reload works.

Comment: This is cool. But I am understanding you correct that now I cannot have Blazor Client App?

Comment: The example sets up a WASM SPA.  The server just acts as a web server.

Comment: True. But in that case WASM SPA cannot be hosted as a Azure Static Site

Comment: The hosting site dictates what features you have and what you can and can't do! You didn't state  your hosting option in your question.

Comment: Right. Next time I will. So your solution will not work then I guess?

Comment: @user1144596 NP ;-)  My solution will work with an Azure App Service, but not with the static site.  There's no real way to map multiple endpoints.  You could possibly do a band aid with some JS and the 404 page, but I'm no JS wizard!